# How to view current running queries on a DB

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm using Sqlyog to run queries on a db.

Is there a way to view the all the current running queries on the db (and possibly kill some of them)? If not, what is a recommended tool for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try installing the free [Mysql Administrator](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html). It has a tab where it lists all the queries running on the server.
Probably you can do the same with the command line tools but i think that the administrator is more user friendly.

Answer (score 2):

SHOW PROCESSLIST and then KILL [process number].

Answer (score 1):

You can also get this information by executing the MySQL command [SHOW PROCESSLIST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-processlist.html) or by querying the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/processlist-table.html) table.

Both of these approaches can be used by humans or code to get process list info. You can even do things like:

```
SELECT Time FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST WHERE User = '...' (etc.)
```